# Errors importing routers in Express using Es6

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to import my routers in my express app using Es6 modules it's my first time using Es6 in express i already set ** "type":"module"** in my package.json file but i am having errors coming from my app.js file saying.

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
```

Please i need help with this i have tried some options and it is not working

my auth router

```
import express from "express";
import User from "../model/userModel";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const router = express.Router();


router.post("/SignUp", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const salt = 12;
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    const user = new User({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      email: req.body.email,
      phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
    const saveUser = await user.save();
    res.status(200).json(saveUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err.message);
  }
});


router.post("/SingIn", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const findUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!findUser) {
      return res.json("User not registered");
    } else {
      const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, findUser.password);

      if (!checkPassword) {
        return res.json("Incorrect or Invalid Password");
      } else {
        res.status(200).json("Login Succesfully");
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err.message);
  }
});

export default router;
```

my app.js file

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import authRouter from "./router/authRoutes.js";
const app = express();
// Connecting to MongoDB database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fmDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error connecting to database");
});
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Database Connected"); // Connection Established
});
const PORT = 4000;

// Middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use("/auth", authRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: have you tried to export the router by using "module.exports = router;" instead of export default?

Comment: Yes i tried it and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: what about import User from "../model/userModel.js"; instead of import User from "../model/userModel"; in your Router